# Loop Posts Outside of WordPress Installation

Tags: loop

I am trying to loop posts outside of WordPress installation but for some reason I am getting `500 - include(Requests.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory` error.

**Here is how my code looks:**

```
    <?php 
                require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/blog/wp-load.php'); 
                $args = array(                      
                    'posts_per_page' => 10
                );
                $latest_posts = new WP_Query( $args );  
                if ( $latest_posts->have_posts() ) {
                    while ( $latest_posts->have_posts() ) {
                        $latest_posts->the_post(); ?>
                <li>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"> 
                <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
                        <span class="post_thumbnail"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></span>
                <?php } ?>
                        <span class="post_title"><?php the_title(); ?></span>
                    </a>
                    <span class="post_time">Posted on <?php the_time('l jS F, Y') ?></span>
                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                </li>   
            <? } 
                    } else {
                    echo '<p>There are no posts available</p>';
                }
                wp_reset_postdata();
            ?>
            </ul>
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Have you thought about using the rest API to read posts?

Answer (score 0):

The error is related to a file called Requests.php, that is not a WordPress file. I don't see an include or require for this file in your code.

Eventually you can add this before require, and check for the wp-load.php path

```
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false );
```

But, do this, will not solve the error, may you add the code where Request.php appears ?

Comment: I am trying to loop inside **Yii Framework** so many be that is the issue?

Comment: Maybe but it is an error between where the present file is load and where the assets are. You have to correct their path otherwise your script couldn't stream them.